# jQuery Drag Image to Div

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to set up my site to allow an image to be dragged to one of three slots.  The draggable works just fine, but the drop event is not firing.  I tried adding alerts to the drag-stop event to identify if it was dropped on an area, but that always returns false.  I have debugged the javascript, to no avail.  This whole setup happens in a jQuery dialog box, the spans with the main images are hidden and shown based upon a drop down box selection, and the merch_slots div is dynamically setup.  Any help would be appreciated.

If I could get to the point of getting which image was dragged to which slot, I can take care of the rest.

```
<span id="span_asst" class="merch_image_slots">
<img id="image_merch_1" class="merchandiser_image" alt="image" src="images/image_merch_1.jpg" />
<img id="image_merch_2" class="merchandiser_image" alt="image" src="images/image_merch_2.jpg" />
<img id="image_merch_3" class="merchandiser_image" alt="image" src="images/image_merch_3.jpg" />
</span>

<div class='merch_slots'>
<div id='selected_item1' class='selected_item'>
<img height='250' class='droppable' src='images/merchandiser/image1.jpg' />
</div>
<div id='selected_item2' class='selected_item'>
<img height='250' class='droppable' src='images/merchandiser/image2.jpg' />
</div>
<div id='selected_item3' class='selected_item'>
<img height='250' class='droppable' src='images/merchandiser/image3.jpg' />
</div>
</div>

$( ".merchandiser_image" ).draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: '.container',
    refreshPositions: true,
    cursor: 'move',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $('.droppable').addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.droppable').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        if ( $.ui.ddmanager.drop( $(this).data("draggable"), event ) ) {
            alert( 'was dropped' );
        }
        else {
            alert( 'it was not dropped' );
        }
    }
});


$( ".selected_item" ).droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        alert(targetElem);
    }
});

.selected_item
{
    width:122px;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
    background: white;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    border-color: #20548E;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.merchandiser_image
{
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    border-color: #20548E;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    height:250px;
}
```

Comment: your code works just fine in here http://jsfiddle.net/tamilvendhank/VQfWu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

Hmm, I don't see anything wrong with your code.
I took the liberty of testing it on JSFiddle.

[This was the result](http://jsfiddle.net/srg6F/1/), the image errors aside, doesn't it do what you're describing?
Unless you're just copy pasting segments of your code, I think you're forgetting a [crucial part](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) of JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(){
    //Do stuff
});
```

What I *can* say with absolute certainty, is that there is nothing wrong with the code.
Well... maybe the indentation.

If you think there's something wrong, perhaps you should check out some debugging methods.
Depending on your browser, you've got some options:

- Firefox: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- Chrome: Developer panel
- Internet Explorer: Developer panel (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Opera: [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)

---

## Solution

The solution in it's entirety,
[Here's the example in JSFiddle once again](http://jsfiddle.net/srg6F/1/).

HTML

```
<span id="span_asst" class="merch_image_slots">
    <img id="image_merch_1" class="merchandiser_image" alt="image" src="images/image_merch_1.jpg" />
    <img id="image_merch_2" class="merchandiser_image" alt="image" src="images/image_merch_2.jpg" />
    <img id="image_merch_3" class="merchandiser_image" alt="image" src="images/image_merch_3.jpg" />
</span>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".merchandiser_image" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        containment: '.container',
        refreshPositions: true,
        cursor: 'move',
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            $('.droppable').addClass('ui-state-highlight');
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $('.droppable').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            if ( $.ui.ddmanager.drop( $(this).data("draggable"), event ) ) {
                alert( 'was dropped' );
            }
            else {
                alert( 'it was not dropped' );
            }
        }
    });


    $( ".selected_item" ).droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");
            $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            alert(targetElem);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.selected_item
{
    width:122px;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
    background: white;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    border-color: #20548E;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.merchandiser_image
{
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    border-color: #20548E;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px;
    height:250px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured out what I had done wrong. I had the droppable declaration in the wrong spot.  Since the item that the droppable was being attached to was dynamically created, at the time the droppable was declared, the item did not exist.  I moved it to its proper place, and it worked correctly.